# Concatenar string à todos os href da página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função no jQuery que possa concatenar aos hrefs da página uma string.

Minha página se comporta de uma maneira diferente se minha url conter `#es` ou `#pr`, então queria manter esse comentário no final de cada link.

Exemplo:

```
<a href="/pagina/">Página</a>
```

se tornaria, caso o comentário `#pr` estiver na url

```
<a href="/pagina/#pr">Página</a>
```

Mas queria fazer isso com todos os links da página.

Uma função que capture todos os `href`'s e que possa coloca-los depois de tratados nos devidos lugares também serviria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para trocar o valor pode ser algo do tipo:

```js
$('a').each(function(index,item){
  var link = $(this).prop('href') + "#pr";
  $(this).prop('href', link);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/pagina/">Página 1</a>
<a href="/pagina/">Página 2</a>
<a href="/pagina/">Página 3</a>
```

Dessa forma é possível iterar por todos os links e alterar a propriedade de cada um.

Answer (score 0):

fiz uma breve busca e achei isto.

Podes usar este código Jquery :`$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){});`
Ele detecta mudança na url, você pode capturar a nova url e concatenar seu código antes da "url original". Adicionando assim suas tags.

Tópico com JSfiddle : [Tópico StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349907/how-can-i-trigger-on-url-change-in-jquery)

Abraço e sucesso na sua jornada.